# How do I check my database with a cronjob in Symfony 4 so I can alter it if necessary?

Tags: php, symfony, cron

I am currently working on a web app that runs on Symfony 4.
I have however encountered a problem while doing so.
I have a database that holds awards. They have some properties, but most importantly, they expire. And I want to do something once they did. I thought of doing this with a cronjob. So basically a cronjob checks every 10 minutes or so, whether or not the award has expired and if so, he is supposed to make an API call with the primary key of that award, which handles how I want to treat that award. Can I do that? Or is there something easier in Symfony that does just that, but without cron?

Comment: You could request non expired rewards when there is an API call, and a cronjob every day to remove from DB your expired rewards ?

Comment: Yes, I want to do something like that, but I don't know how I link my cronjob with all the symfony stuff. I want the cronjob to first check if there are any awards that expired, but I don't know how I access my database from my cronjob, and then do the API call if neccessary.

Comment: I believe your approach is slightly flawed. The logic should be completely inside/part of your symfony application. the cronjob simply *triggers* that behavior. I see two sub-approaches: 1. make a route for this and somehow trigger this, via service or cron or the cron symfony bundle Ali Kazemi linked. 2. make a symfony console command, which you call from a cron job (environment is a bit annoying though).

Answer (score 2):

yes. you can do that.

There is no feature in Symfony to do that simpler than cron . you should use cron.

you should declare a public action  to check for awards in one of your controllers and call that action from cron.

if you want you can also use this bundle:

https://github.com/Cron/Symfony-Bundle